# permission for my php to create a dynamic file on the server

Tags: php

For a project I need my php file to create a dynamic file (on remote server which I bought)  which loads into a flash component. Everything is working fine on my localhost. But once I upload it to the server, it throws the following errors:

```
Warning: fopen(output.html) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\x.co.in\httpdocs\blabla.php on line 25
Warning: DOMDocument::save(k_id.xml) [domdocument.save]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\x.co.in\httpdocs\blabla.php on line 136
```

where on those lines fopen is written.

I understood as there is no permission to my php file to create any dynamic files on the server.  So i just wanna understand is there a way by which I can privilege my php to create that file on the server.

I've the login access, which I think I've to put somewhere in code before it tries to create such file...but i dont know how to figure this...any suggestions?

Comment: I went to control panel from where I've given privileges to my code to generate such file. thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

The user that runs the PHP process needs to have permissions to write new files in the target folder. On linux servers this is done using [CHMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).

```
chmod 777 -R /path/to/folder
```

777 is the permission (full permission for testing only), -R means recursive for the files/folders inside. As you are using windows just right click on the folder and look at properties and search for permissions.

Comment: did 777 but it says command not understood, it is rolling back the changes from 777 to default

Answer (score 0):

Create a new directory where the PHP will write the files. For that directory set permissions to `705` (that is owner has Read, Write, Execute permission)

You can either do that using a FTP client (Filezilla) or via a Bash shell

```
mkdir inputfiles   
chmod 705 inputfiles
```

Comment: did 705 but it says command not understood, it is rolling back the changes from 705 to default

Comment: @pbvamsi Are you doing this in a bash shell? Did you hit `enter` after both the commands?

Comment: am using filezilla, windows...did the changes to directory, but it is rolling back to default

Comment: if you are using filezilla, just right click on the directory, click on 'set permissions' and select Read, Write and Execute under 'Owner'. if that doesn't work, try to above commands through a bash shell.